# How can I type in multiple lines using Tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new to programming and tkinter in general. Here I will show the part of the code which I am struggling with. I thought by making this widget bigger it will let me type in multiple lines, but obviously it didn't. What should I do to have this entry allow the user to type in multiple lines after clicking the "enter" button for example?

````
tweet_text = tk.Entry(post_window, width = 33)
tweet_text.grid(ipadx = 49, ipady = 49, row = 0 , column = 0)```

Thank you!
````

Comment: For multiple lines use the Text Widget instead.

Comment: You cannot, thats why there is a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry widget is used for typing in quite short inputs, for larger inputs use the `Text` widget.

```
from tkinter import *

def take():
    print(t.get(1.0,'end-1c'))

root = Tk()
t = Text(root,height=10,width=50)
t.pack(padx=10)

b = Button(root,text='Click me',command=take)
b.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This is a simple code to show and get all the text from the textbox.

[For more info on Text widget, click here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Hope this cleared your doubts, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers